# Create floating chat heads like facebook messenger

Tags: android, react-native

Is it possible to create floating chat heads like facebook messenger by using android with content is created by React Native?

Comment: What do you mean by android React native content?

Comment: It's mean i will code view content of each tab sector using React Native and glue it into tab view that is created by java code (android).

Answer (score 0):

As this would be a native feature it would be more optimal for you to simply create this feature within your android app itself. Personally, I can't find any library that helps do this from react-native.

Comment: I found an android library for creating chat head with native development: [Google Hover](https://github.com/google/hover) but I've an issue that is instead using View instance as content of each tab I wanna using my React Native module. I referred to [integrate RN to Android app](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) and I saw following line:  `mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager,"MyReactNativeApp", null);`  
then I used _mReactRootView_ as View to pass into tab view. But when application running, nothing is displayed.